# No common encryption algorithm(s) (ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Tags: ssl, openssl

My clients are reporting this error. I cannot reproduce it. What's more, I cannot detect any flaws: http://www.digicert.com/ http://www.ssltest.net/ https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/ all report `dev.anuary.com` to have a valid cert. I've Google(ed) for `ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap`, but none of the threads provided any useful guidance.

```
Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)

(Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)
```

- CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
- OpenSSL 1.0.0-20.el6_2.3
- nginx 1.0.15-1.el6.ngx
- Using http://www.networksolutions.com/SSL-certificates/index.jsp Wildcard certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out the issue was that:

> Since version 1.0.5, nginx uses “ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1” and
>   “ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5” by default

(http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains)

I've added the following to my settings and it works.

```
ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```

Comment: So, your clients were actually set (unusually) to use just TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2?

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm seeing this:

```
$ sslscan --no-failed dev.anuary.com
               _
       ___ ___| |___  ___ __ _ _ __
      / __/ __| / __|/ __/ _` | '_ \
      \__ \__ \ \__ \ (_| (_| | | | |
      |___/___/_|___/\___\__,_|_| |_|

              Version 1.8.2
         http://www.titania.co.uk
    Copyright Ian Ventura-Whiting 2009

Testing SSL server dev.anuary.com on port 443

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA

  Prefered Server Cipher(s):
    TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
```

Is it possible the client can't do TLSv1?

Comment: This have been reported by people using Firefox 2.*, Firefox 3.6.* and IE 8.

Comment: On IE8, I seem to be able to get to the 404, so the connection is successful in terms of SSL negotiation.  If I go and turn off TLSv1 in Internet Options, I get a connection error.  Is it possible the users have disabled TLSv1 for some reason?  Are they behind some SSL appliance that might have disabled TLSv1?

Comment: FWIW, mail.google.com still supports SSLv3.  Is there any reason you've limited yourself to TLSv1?

Comment: Is this something I set, or is it something that comes with my SSL cert and I cannot change? If it is the former, what settings should I change.

Comment: On a side note, when I've checked my site using http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/report/?fqdn=dev.anuary.com&protocol=https it says `No connection upgrade to 128-bit for old browsers`. I wonder how to enable that.

Comment: The TLSv1 vs. SSLv3 thing is not a property of the cert.  That's nginx configuration.  Can you update your question with the relevant SSL config for nginx?  To specify the cipher protocols, you'd have a line somewhere like "ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;" and to specify the ciphers, you'd have something like "ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;"  Those two lines will disallow weak ciphers sufficiently to pass some level of security audit (I forget to which standard), actually.

Comment: The 128-bit thing, I get that on my site also, so I'm not sure if that's indicative.  On the other hand, I'm not using old browsers, e.g., FF2.